# Lenovo Thinkpad E15 (2nd Gen): Special function keys don't work with openSUSE Leap 15.3

Tags: linux, lenovo-laptop, opensuse, function-keys

The whole story can be found in [openSUSE Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1185264), but here is the summary:

For openSUSE Leap 15.3 the "special function keys" (media keys, etc.) do not work, or do not work reliably for a Lenovo Thinkpad E15 (2nd Gen).

I'd like to use the special keys, and most specifically the feature to suspend/resume the laptop without having to shutdown/power-off and restart/power-on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I don't understand the mechanisms involved, I found out that a BIOS update fixes the issue, while kernel updates seemingly did not.

I had BIOS version "R1AET34W (1.10)" (Date: "12/19/2020"), and after having updated it to 1.17 "R1AET41W (1.17)" (Date: "11/11/2021") the problems were gone.

See also https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1185264#c12.